# Why is my jQuery complete function called before animate is finish?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

```
<button onclick="$.MyObject.add('wrapper');">Add</button>
```

Somewhere in the code I did:

```
$.MyObject= new MyUberObject();
```

then in my **add** function, I specify my call back, and invoke the animation and pass my callback to it.

```
function MyUberObject(data) {
  ...
  this.add = function(name, index) {
     var callback = function(n,i) { 
              $.MyObject.addDiv(n, i); 
              alert("wtf");
           }(name, index);

     $("#outerWrapper").animate(
        {
           "width": "+=200px",             
        }, 
        {
           duration : "fast",
           easing: "linear",
           complete: callback
        }               
     );
  ...
}
```

However the alert come up immediately as soon as the button is pressed, then once I cleared the alert, the animation would go... I've tried many different ways of specifying the callback, as well as try to use delay and call it in other places... still no go.

Comment: I use alert("wtf") in my debugging of js as well! Just don't forget to take it out prior to launch... could be embarrassing. :)

Comment: hah.  you are right in needing to use the closure, but see my response, you are close.  - edit, although I guess you don't really need the closure, I thought it was being run within a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 var callback = function(n,i) { 
          $.MyObject.addDiv(n, i); 
          alert("wtf");
       }(name, index);
```

You are calling the callback here, that's why it's getting called.

Try doing this, I think name and index should exist due to closure.

```
function MyUberObject(data) {
  ...
  this.add = function(name, index) {

     var callback = function() { 
              $.MyObject.addDiv(name, index); 
              alert("wtf");
           };

     $("#outerWrapper").animate(
        {
           "width": "+=200px",             
        }, 
        {
           duration : "fast",
           easing: "linear",
           complete: callback
        }               
     );
  ...
}
```

if not then you can add the name and index to the outerwrapper:

```
function MyUberObject(data) {
  ...
  this.add = function(name, index) {

     var callback = function() { 
              $.MyObject.addDiv($(this).data("props").name, $(this).data("props").index); 
              alert("wtf");
           };

     $("#outerWrapper").data("props", {name : name, index : index};
     $("#outerWrapper").animate(
        {
           "width": "+=200px",             
        }, 
        {
           duration : "fast",
           easing: "linear",
           complete: callback
        }               
     );
  ...
}
```

or maybe even simpler...

```
function MyUberObject(data) {
  ...
  this.add = function(name, index) {

     var callback = function(n, i) { 
              $.MyObject.addDiv(n, i); 
              alert("wtf");
           };

     $("#outerWrapper").animate(
        {
           "width": "+=200px",             
        }, 
        {
           duration : "fast",
           easing: "linear",
           complete: function(){callback(name, index);}
        }               
     );
  ...
}
```

Comment: The first solution works. Weird, at some point I tried it without passing (name, index) into it before and it would throw error. But many thanks, was hammering on this since last night!

Answer (score 2):

you're using a self executing function, that's why you see the alert.  try using using the anonymous self executing function with a return statement.

```
var callback = function(n,i) { 
  return function(){
    $.MyObject.addDiv(n, i); 
  }
}(name, index);
```

[Closures - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Answer (score 2):

```
var tmp = function () {
  console.log("automatically executed!");
}();

var tmp = function () {
  console.log("Executed when invoked!");
}
```

So wait with invoking your callback.