# Why does jQuery .animate callback occur before the animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Why is the callback on this `.animate` function happening, before the animation?

Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/93Qyq/7/

This is the Javascript portion:

```
$('#clickButton').click(function() {
  $('.spanClass').animate({
    left: '+=200'
  }, 500, positionReset());
});

function positionReset(){
    alert('complete!');
   $('.spanClass').animate({'left':'-=200'})
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="divClass">
<span id="a" class="spanClass">A</span>
<span id="b" class="spanClass">B</span>
<span id="c" class="spanClass">C</span>
</div>
<br>
<div id="clickButton">CLICK BUTTON</div><br>​
```

​

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my jQuery complete function called before animate is finish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638212/why-is-my-jquery-complete-function-called-before-animate-is-finish)

Answer (score 6):

That's because you're not passing your function to `animate()` -- you're *calling it*, and passing *the value it returns* (which is not a function, and is subsequently ignored by the framework).

You have to remove the parentheses after your function:

```
$('.spanClass').animate({
    left: '+=200'
}, 500, positionReset);  // No parentheses.
```

Instead of:

```
$('.spanClass').animate({
    left: '+=200'
}, 500, positionReset());
```

Comment: as a note, you could also use an anonymous function like `function() { positionReset(); }` for cases where you might want to do something else after calling `positionReset()`.

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
$('#clickButton').click(function() {
  $('.spanClass').animate({
    left: '+=200'
  }, 500, positionReset); //not positionReset() or you will autocall callback function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are invoking the function by putting brackets after it. To pass a reference to the function you just use it's name, without the brackets. e.g.

```
$('#clickButton').click(function() {
  $('.spanClass').animate({
    left: '+=200'
  }, 500, positionReset);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`positionReset()` will call the function as its a function call. You need to **pass the function object to the animate callback** as `positionReset`

See THE [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/adesew/4/edit)

```
$('#clickButton').click(function() {
  $('.spanClass').animate({
    left: '+=200'
  }, 500, positionReset);
});
```